# count sum and average of 3rd column if the conditions of 1st two columns are true

Tags: linux, bash, awk, bioinformatics

[I am new to awk and linux and help will be really appreciated.
If the 4th column has CACTA and the 8th column has CDS, it should count the number of CACTA in CDS and sum the number of bases covered in the 9th column.

I am trying awk but it is not working, it gives back the total count of CACTA in the 4th column and about the sum, I am not sure how to do that.

awk '{$4=="CACTA_TIR_transposon" && $8=="CDS"}' inputfile | wc -l

][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HdQB.png

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Replace image with its text.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
A01     4132    8206    CACTA_TIR_transposon    A01     3046    6243    gene    2111
A01     4132    8206    CACTA_TIR_transposon    A01     3046    6243    mRNA    2111
A01     4132    8206    CACTA_TIR_transposon    A01     3046    6243    CDS     1
A01     4132    8206    CACTA_TIR_transposon    A01     3046    6243    CDS     2
A01     4132    8206    CACTA_TIR_transposon    A01     3046    6243    CDS     3

$ awk '$4=="CACTA_TIR_transposon" && $8=="CDS"{cnt+=1; sum+=$9}END{printf "Count: %d, Sum: %d\n", cnt, sum}' file
Count: 3, Sum: 6
```